# Parallel Processing while writing to file

Tags: python, parallel-processing, data-science

I have a csv file with around 5million lines, I want to read every line, scrape some data then append it to the end of the line. As this takes time, I want to do this process in parallel (the computation isn't intensive on it's own so I'm not looking at multi-threading, just running in parallel).

Then I want to write all the lines into a new file.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this, so far I have the loop, function but i need to write the write_to_file function and the parallelisation function. Any tips on the best way to do this and which libraries to use?

Thanks!

Comment: If the computation is short then you'll be I/O bound and parallelization won't speed it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "scrape some data"? Are you just processing the line? Or are you scraping as in getting pages from the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joblib` package to parallelize this operation.

```
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
import time
now = time.time()
def process_one_line(line):
    # Write your logic to process one line
    # e.g., I am appending "_modified" on each line
    return line + "_modified"

# Read your file
with open("bigfile.txt","r") as fp:
    modified_lines = Parallel(n_jobs=1000, prefer='threads')(delayed(process_one_line) (line) for line in fp)


# Write to new file
with open("modified_bigfile.txt","w") as fp:
    Parallel(n_jobs=1000, prefer='threads')(delayed(fp.write) (line) for line in modified_lines)

print(f"Total Time taken - {(time.time() - now)/60}")
```

I tested this code. It took approx `1.54 mins` to modify the `49M` file which was pretty nice. Also, you can increase the value for `n_jobs` if you want it to make it faster.

`prefer` argument can take `threads` or `processes`. My computer crashed when I tried `processes` as my `n_jobs` was `1000`

You can read more about `joblib` [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)